# Why Radio button is not selected by default?

Tags: angular

```js
export class CompositesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
}
```

```html
<div class="input" style="padding-top: 1%;">
  <mat-label>Select an option for the calculation</mat-label><br/>
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="weight calculation" formControlName="aircraftWeightSelection" color="primary" (change)="OnAircraftWeightSelection($event)">
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2%" value="FinalPartWeight" [checked]='true'>First Part weight</b></mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2% ;vertical-align: top;" [disabled]='isMaterialWeightNotProvided' value="MaterialWeight">Second Part weight </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2%; vertical-align: top;" value="PartWeightDifference">Third Part weight</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

I have three radio buttons.By default first button should be selected.How to set it?

Select an option for the calculation
          
            First Part weight
            Second Part Weight 
            Third Part Weight

Comment: Could you provide the entire typescript code of your CompositesComponent ?

Comment: It works fine for me, the first option is selected. Though you have a floating </b> there in the first radio button that doesn't work in this example.

Comment: No, by default no button is selected. Check the docs

Comment: Check SO for the same question

Answer (score 0):

> I have three radio buttons.By default first button should be
> selected.How to set it?

Here is how you do it in reactive forms,

```
this.yourForm = this.fb.group(
        {
          aircraftWeightSelection: ['FinalPartWeight']
        }
      );
```

so your component file can look like this,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'stackoverflow-examples';
    panelOpenState = false;
    yourForm: FormGroup;
    isMaterialWeightNotProvided: boolean = true;

    get aircraftWeightSelectionFormControl(): FormControl {
      // debugger
      return this.yourForm.controls['aircraftWeightSelection'] as FormControl;
    }

    constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { 
      this.yourForm = this.fb.group(
        {
          aircraftWeightSelection: ['FinalPartWeight']
        }
      );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

  OnAircraftWeightSelection(evt: any) {
    // Do your thing here
  }
}
```

Your HTML file can look like this,

```
<div class="input" style="padding-top: 1%;">
  <mat-label>Select an option for the calculation</mat-label><br/>
  <mat-radio-group aria-label="weight calculation" [formControl]="aircraftWeightSelectionFormControl" color="primary" (change)="OnAircraftWeightSelection($event)">
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2%" value="FinalPartWeight">First Part weight</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2% ;vertical-align: top;" [disabled]='isMaterialWeightNotProvided' value="MaterialWeight">Second Part weight </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button style="padding-top: 2%; vertical-align: top;" value="PartWeightDifference">Third Part weight</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

**Note: This is just a code sample for your question you may still have to modify this a little :) happy coding !**

Comment: Please do  not "feed"  with answer. OP should do some research by themsleves. SO and other supports, even the docs for AM have many resources that answer their question. OP should make an effort

Comment: think when you started for the first time :) was it same for you?

Comment: SO is not a forum. We are not here as just helpers, but to build a strong wiki. And when I was new, I indeed searched a lot, like a mad before posting. That is what is recommended: search, search, search before posting. It is an essential skill to have as a programmer

Comment: Check this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5468463 and the anwers